# Fragment gets recreated on click from BottonNavigationBar with NavController

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

So I have a GoogleMap in Fragment A, whenever I select fragment B from the BottomNavigationBar and select Fragment A again, the Map is reinitialised. However, if I go back to fragment A by back-press, the mapview is restored to it's previous state.

```
    private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navigationContainer) as NavHostFragment
    navHostFragment.navController.setGraph(R.navigation.main_graph)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavigationBar, navHostFragment.navController)

    binding.bottomNavigationBar.setOnItemReselectedListener {
        // Do nothing to ignore the reselection
    }
}
```

The fragment transaction are being handled by the NavigationComponenet itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/home_graph">

<include app:graph="@navigation/home_graph"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/captain_portal_graph"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/accounts_graph"/>

</navigation>
```

My fragments extend this BaseFragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<TViewBinding : ViewDataBinding> : Fragment() {

private var innerBinding: TViewBinding? = null
protected val binding: TViewBinding get() = innerBinding ?: throw IllegalStateException("Trying to access the binding outside of the lifecycle.")

abstract val layoutId: Int

protected val baseActivity: BaseActivity<*>
    get() = activity as BaseActivity<*>

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    innerBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    setupActionBar()
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    innerBinding = null
}
```

This official [sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample) from Google is working as expected, I want to achieve the same behavior, what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your graph define your navigation action that leads to your map fragment with `app:launchSingleTop="true"`.

> `app:launchSingleTop` : Whether this navigation action should launch as single-top (i.e., there will be at most one copy of a given destination on the top of the back stack)

source: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavOptions

to have the navigation component in sync with the normal back press navigation you must also add `app:defaultNavHost="true"` to your fragment container view.

> the `app:defaultNavHost="true"` attribute ensures that your NavHostFragment intercepts the system Back button. Note that only one NavHost can be the default. If you have multiple hosts in the same layout (two-pane layouts, for example), be sure to specify only one default NavHost.

source: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started

Comment: I'm not using any actions to navigate to fragments so I cannot add app:launchSingleTop. I'm letting the navigation components automatically handle the bottom sheet bar navigations.
Where/how do you suggest I go about this?

Comment: that is not possible. Navigation component has 3 key elements:the host, the navigation graph and the navigation controller. I have looked into the sample app and there is a navigation graph with 3 sub-graphs each containing at least one action. The purpose of the navigation component is to give you more control over your app navigation while hiding the fragment transactions over the hood. Having an empty graph defies this purpose. You should use the "on tab selected/on item selected" callback of your navigation bar together with your nav component.

Comment: I do have actions but for inner fragments. My point was, that my mapfragment is the startDestination of the subgraph "home". It isn't directed by any action. It is being handled by the bottom navigation menu items, just like the sample has.